# Adwords Script Failed to read from AdWords. Please wait a bit and try again

Tags: google-ads-api

I wrote an adwords script in order to pause all the ads (with a specific Label) belonging to a specific Adgroup.

But when I run it, an error ocurred "Failed to read from AdWords. Please wait a bit and try again."
This error ocurred because of this Line ".withCondition("LabelNames CONTAINS 'TEST'")"

When I delete this line, the code works without any issue.

```
  var campaignsIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns()
  .withCondition("Name CONTAINS 'SPECIFIC CAMPAIGN'")
  .get();

  if(!campaignsIterator.hasNext()){
    Logger.log("No Campaign");
  }else{

    while (campaignsIterator.hasNext()) {
      var campaign = campaignsIterator.next();

      var adGroupIterator = campaign.adGroups()
      .withCondition("Name CONTAINS 'SPECIFIC ADGROUP'")
      .get();

      while (adGroupIterator.hasNext()) {
        var adGroup = adGroupIterator.next();
        Logger.log("Campaign : " + campaign.getName() + " | AdGroup : " + adGroup.getName());

        var adIteratorNormal = adGroup.ads()
        .withCondition("LabelNames CONTAINS 'LABEL-TEST'") 
        .withCondition("Type = TEXT_AD")
        .get()

        while(adIteratorNormal.hasNext()){
          var ads = adIteratorNormal.next();

           if(ads.isEnabled()){
             ads.pause;
           }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
```

I would like to know how can I do to solve this issue.
Thank you
Pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue: replace "CONTAINS 'LABEL-TEST'" by "CONTAINS_ANY ['LABEL-TEST']"

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-scripts/pqH0i1_YKDo